# How to properly create an overlay view in storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

My aim is to create a popup view right below a button once is clicked, this is the concept:

[image]

The way I prepared the storyboard is by using two different UIViewController. The main one contains the two buttons and, once clicked, I modally push the second UIViewController over the current context.

[image]

My question is: what's the best or properly way to create constrain in order to move the "Tapped" image right below the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I do this is to add a childcontroller to your first storyboard vc. Then adjust the frame of the container view in the storyboard, which I hope will be easier than programmatically adjusting frames.

[image]

Then be sure to change the class on top of the VC that Xcode created for you.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When the button is clicked get the the bottom position of it (it's y in frame + height) and send it to the popup , then set them as the **top** constraint of the imageView in popup in **viewDidLayoutSubview**

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the position of the overlay using the button's and the `view`'s positions and dimensions. For example, the overlay's y can be the button's `frame.maxY + constant`.

```
let x = ...
let y = ...
let width = ...
let height = ...
let overlay = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height))
 view.addSubView(overlay)
```

The translucent black view can be added as a `UIView` with the same frame as the `view` of the VC and constrained to always be the same as the frame of the VC's `view`. Add this view first, before you add `overlay`.